# Using SimpleXML to send images between Android and Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, multimedia, simple-framework

Today I'm presented with a challange of writing an XML that will hold image files. I don't know how to go about this but I need to have an image on Java and that will use SimpleXML write method to send an image from one Socket to the Socket in Android.

Is this possible?

I've tried looking around but I seem to have trouble with that.

If this is possible, is it also possible to use other multimedia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research I have solved this problem by creating a ByteArray in SimpleXML, putting the image into the byte array in Java and then recreating it as bitmap in android using bitmap factory. Hope this helps anyone in their future endeavors.